# Hide elements for specific language in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

Is there any way I could hide specific content for different languages in localization in Xcode? I want to hide a button(for now), and change an outgoing link for a button, but a general answear would be appreciated.

Thank you for ideas.

Comment: The only way I know is to get the current device or app language and programmatically change the link and hide button.

Comment: Bro, why should you change a link for hided buttons?

Comment: I need to change a link for one button and hide another :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current device locale through `Locale` class,

```
let locale = Locale.current.languageCode
```

Now for example, if you want to enable button and show the proper link for `English`(**en**) only then,

```
if locale == "en" {
    //show the button and update with the outgoing link
} else {
    //hide the button
}
```

Comment: glad to help you